# Why won't the len() function output anything in python 3.1.2?

Tags: python, list

I installed the 3.1.2 IDLE python console, then I entered this code:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> len(a)
4
```

Directly from the python official docs http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

But it does not work in the interpreter as it should, it does not return 4.

What am I doing wrong? Are the official docs wrong?

I've looked in a few other sites but many are talking about Python 2.x.

Comment: please provide more detail. what operating system are you on? are you using the standard cpython interpreter and shell?

Comment: Do you get an error returned?

Comment: No error, Windows XP SP3, standar unmodified Python 3.1.2 shell, the only way it would return 4 is if i do this print (len(a))

Comment: Works fine on my 32 bit 3.1.2 install on win7. How about a screenshot so we can see exactly what you did?

Comment: Oh well, it turns out is not that simple as i put it, i'm using notepad++ and then calling python console with this C:\Python31\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
And i get nothing, strange thing, because if i open python.exe directly it and try the code it does output 
4

Comment: How exactly did you start the interpreter (in Notepad++)?

Comment: you need to `print( .. )` stuff to show it when you're not running in interactive mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no bug; you have misunderstood what should happen.

Python can be called interactively (by running `python.exe` at the prompt). This mode automatically prints the result of a line when it is finished, for ease of reading/debugging. However, it's not very useful for writing any serious amount of code.

The way do to that is to put the code in a script (a plain text file with a `.py` ending on Windows) and call the script with `python.exe foo.py`. In this case, something else happens: Python executes the script and does not automatically print the result of every line. That's what the `print` function/statement is for. Write `print(len(a))` instead.

Note that this has nothing to do with the version of Python you are using.